# Is a pre-departure COVID test still required for entry into Japan?

Tags: covid-19, japan

There seems to be conflicting advice on the official Ministry of Foreign Affairs website:

https://www.mofa.go.jp/ca/fna/page25e_000334.html

says it is necessary to present a certificate of inspection from within 72 hours before departure, but:

https://www.mhlw.go.jp/stf/covid-19/border_test.html

implies that this requirement is waived for 3-times vaccinated folk. There were some newspaper articles suggesting the same thing has applied since 7 September 2022.

What is the reality on the ground?

Answer (score 2):

TIMATIC, which is what airlines go off on border requirements states :

Emphasis mine

> **Passengers must have a negative COVID-19 test result**. Tests accepted
> are: CLEIA/ECLIA quantitative antigen test, LAMP, NEAR, Next
> Generation Sequence, PCR, RT-PCR, Smart Amp, TMA or TRC. The test must
> be taken at most 72 hours before departure from the first embarkation
> point, and the test certificate must be in English. The test
> certificate must also specify that the test is based on a
> "nasopharyngeal swab", or "saliva", or "nasopharyngeal and
> oropharyngeal swab". A "nasal swab" is also accepted if the test type
> is LAMP, NEAR, PCR, RT-PCR, Smart Amp, TMA or TRC. Details can be
> found at https://www.mhlw.go.jp/stf/covid-19/border_test.html and
> https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/000905811.pdf .
>
> **This does not apply to passengers with a COVID-19 vaccination
> certificate showing that they were fully vaccinated and received a
> booster dose.** Vaccines accepted are: AstraZeneca (Vaxzevria), Covaxin,
> Covovax, Janssen, Moderna (Spikevax), Nuvaxovid (Novavax) and
> Pfizer-BioNTech (Comirnaty). A combination of vaccines is accepted.
> The certificate must be in English, Japanese or accompanied by a
> certified English or Japanese translation. This exemption also applies
> to their accompanying children under 18 years.
>
> This does not apply to passengers younger than 6 or 7 years depending on the school starting age in the country where they reside.
> More details can be found at:
> https://www.theglobaleconomy.com/rankings/Primary_school_starting_age/
>
> This does not apply to US military personnel, civilian personnel, and their dependents. They must have SOFA status and have the required
> documents stipulated in Article IX of the US-Japan Status of Forces
> Agreement.
>
> This does not apply to passengers with a consular letter specifying why the test could not be taken.
>
> Passengers could be subject to a COVID-19 test upon arrival and
> quarantine for 3 days. Details can be found at
> https://www.mhlw.go.jp/stf/covid-19/bordercontrol.html and
> https://www.mhlw.go.jp/content/000945853.pdf
>
> Passengers must complete a "Quarantine Questionnaire" through the
> MySOS app or at https://arqs-qa.followup.mhlw.go.jp/ . This will
> generate a QR code which must be presented upon arrival.
>
> Passengers must install the "MySOS" mobile app before departure or
> upon arrival. More details can be found at
> https://www.hco.mhlw.go.jp/fasttrack/en/

So, as of 17 September, no airlines will ever let you board without a conforming COVID Test if you aren't vaccinated with 3 doses.

You don't need the test if you are vaccinated